# How can I return different structure objects from the same function in rust such as python methods which can return anything?

Tags: generics, rust, enums, return, structure

I am a newbee who is trying to learn rust by doing a side project.
I am currently trying to return multiple object type from the same function in rust. Please look at the below example:

```
// I am currently having a base structure A
pub struct A{
    ...
}

// three more structures uses the base structure:
pub struct B{
    a: A,
    s: String
}

pub struct C{
    a: A,
    s: String
}

pub struct D{
    a: A,
    s: String
}

// Now a function I am writing here which needs to return an object of any of the above mention structures i.e. an object of either B,C or D:
fn func(a:A,s:String) -> B or C or D{
    return obj of B
    or return obj of C
    or return obj of D
}
```

I tried to use enums, but I guess I am not proficient enough in rust to use that. I also tried to use generic types but still not much clear in that area.
Any help will be much appriciated... thanks in advance.

Comment: Typically you will want to return an enum in these cases. Alternatively you can return an anonymous trait that all of these types implement. Can we see what you tried for using enums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an enum:

```rust
// your structs A, B, C, D

enum BCD {
    B(B),
    C(C),
    D(D),
}
fn func(a:A,s:String) -> BCD {
    let return_b = true;
    let return_c = false;
    if return_b {
        BCD::B(B{ a, s })
    } else if return_c {
        BCD::C(C{ a, s })
    } else {
        BCD::D(D{ a, s })
    }
}
```